# Extract text outside HTML tag with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, regex

Lets say I have the following markup:
`<a href="#">My Link <span>And More</span></a>`
How can I extract only `My Link` with jQuery without the content of the `<span>`?

Comment: try this `[^<>]*(?=<span>)` https://regex101.com/r/uM3bR7/3

Comment: @AvinashRaj what if `span` has some attributes?

Comment: `[^<>]*(?=<span\b[^<>]*>)` or `[^<>]*(?=<span.*?>.*?<\/span>)`

Comment: @AvinashRaj never use regex to parse HTML, it's to dynamic. You could write dozens of examples that would break the regex.

Comment: @Mouser yep i know, so that i posted the above regex as comment.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Filter it out using the nodeType:

```
var txt = $('a').contents().filter(function(){
    return this.nodeType === 3;
}).text();
```

### -DEMO-

Comment: The other examples here are doing sort of the same. However your example is far more superior. Could you explain to the other posters here why your example is the most robust one?

Answer (score 0):

From: https://javahelpworld.wordpress.com/2014/04/14/jquery-get-the-text-of-element-without-child-element/

```
jQuery.fn.justtext = function() {

    return $(this)  .clone()
            .children()
            .remove()
            .end()
            .text();

};

$('a').justtext(); //call like this for any element
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var txt1 = $('a').text();
var txt2 = $('a').children().text();
var ret = txt1.slice(0, txt1.indexOf(txt2));
console.log(ret);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var htmlTags = '<span class="prinse-txt">This is my test text</span>';
var textFromHtmlTags = $(htmlTags).text()
```